# Change javascript to grab an id from a form button rather than a select menu?

Tags: javascript, forms

here is the working code for the drop down:

```
function makeSelection(icon, id) {
    if(!icon || !id) return;
    var elem = icon.elements[id];
    if(!elem) return;
    var val = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].id;
    opener.targetElement.value = val;
    this.close();
}
```

HTML:

```
 <form id="icon" name="icon" action="#">
    <select name="icon">
      <option value="value" id="id">Holly</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="makeSelection(this.form, 'icon');">
  </form>
```

here is what I would like the javascript to select instead of a select dropdown I would like it to select on a button click like this:

```
<td>Icon1 Here<br />
<input type="button" value="Select" id="1000" 
       onclick="makeSelection(this.form, 'icon');">
```

the script errors out on this line, I don't actually know what I have to change to make it work with a single click of a button ?

```
var val = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].id;
```

can anyone help on this issue please?

Comment: Its difficult to understand what you want the result to be.

Comment: ok so, the form on the parent page has an button and that button opens up in a child page, and this child page has a selection of icon(pics and under these pics is a choose button, when they see the icon they like they click choose and the child page closes and inputs id of button in the parents icon text input frild, the code above is all the child frame code, which is where it is stuck at

Comment: an example of my working code is here http://www.jamboozah.com/script_files/icons.html the drop down at the bottom is working code but I would like it to go what it does on the drop down for single select buttons as shown on the top of the page.